# How to create dynamic tables/fields in asp.net similar to phpMyAdmin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dynamic

I just wanna ask if there's a way in C#/ASP.NET to create 'dynamic' tables/fields similar to phpMyAdmin:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions/comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear if you want code here or a tool.

If you want code then DDL (something that I suspect a surprisingly large number of people are not *sufficiently* aware) will do the job for you - I'm not sure if there are open source admin projects out there (there's this, but its *way* out of date: http://sourceforge.net/projects/asp-ent-man/) - ah, the MS one is one Codeplex: http://www.codeplex.com/SqlWebAdmin - again not up to date, but it will almost certainly work.

If you're just after tools then you should probably be on serverfault (-: This isn't exactly what you want as it lives in IIS Manager but it may be of interest: http://www.iis.net/expand/DatabaseManager (the Web Platform Installer is your friend!)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28SQL.80%29.aspx) statement?

Just remember that most DDL statements like CREATE TABLE are RDBMS-specific (i.e. the one I linked to is for SQL Server, the one for MySQL is different as is the one for Oracle, etc).

Answer (score 0):

SQL and ADO.NET. You pass create/update/delete scripts to the database. There are a lot of security precautions to take heed of.

Answer (score 0):

How does PhpAdmin create DYNAMIC tables? To me it looks like it creates normal tables - like any admin tool.

Now, here is a hint:
* From C# you can submit any SQL statement you like, they are basically just text.
* Since the dawn of time, when your ancestors where still hunted by sabretoth tigers, SQL has what is called "DDL" - Data Definition Langauge. Stuff like "CREATE TABLE", "ALTER TABLE", "DROP TABLE".
* They are all properly documented in - the  documentation.

Sorry if that sonds a little snippish, but this is really really really basic SQL.

Comment: my mistake on putting the term 'SQL statement'. I'm very much aware of those. Sorry.